# SharpMap - display an overlay image synchronized with the map (georeferencing functionality)

Tags: c#, .net, gis, geospatial, sharpmap

Using SharpMap (Windows Forms) how can I display an overlay image over the map tile background so that the image scales and moves accordingly with the map zoom and pan? I want to implement a georeferencing like functionality.

I tried using `SharpMap.Layers.GdiImageLayer` but I didn't find a way to position it to a custom position (real world coordinate) - it is getting placed by default at origin [0,0] (the background tile coordinates). Is there a way to define a relation (transformation) to place it in a particular position?

I managed to get closer to a solution using `VectorLayer` with `RasterPointSymbolizer` but the symbol (image loaded for symbol) would need to be transformed on map scaling/zoom (so that corners remain in the same real world coordinates) - the math calculation behind looks a little complicated for a solution that seems more like a workaround than a natural one. As a note - I don't need precise calculation using projection/real geoid as I am doing this only at building level.

Using GDAL - `GeoTIFF` might be a choice here by generating a GeoTIFF based on the original image and making the georeferencing metadata dynamic based on UI controls? The original image is in raster format (JPG) with no geographic metadata.

Is there a better solution?

If VectorLayer - `RasterPointSymbolizer` is the best choice, do you have an example for symbol(image) synchronization with the map view?

Answer (score 1):

As far as i can tell the GdiImageLayer calculates the position based on a world-file (`GdiImageLayer.SetEnvelope()`). [Here](https://github.com/SharpMap/SharpMap/blob/1d0f0efc56a9c1f0478eaa3f1306877dcbfff32e/SharpMap/Layers/GdiImageLayer.cs#L244) is the link to the method. This meta file has to have the same name in the same location but the filetype must be of type *.wld. [There](https://webhelp.esri.com/arcims/9.3/General/topics/author_world_files.htm) you set the position (top left corner) and the skew in x and y axis. So rotation will be perserved. I never tried this but i would suggest correct zooming would work

(The [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file) article offers also some good understanding for world files)

There might be another way if no world file is present and the information rests in the header. There is a GDalSample loading a GeoTiff Image onto an existing map. The example can be found in the WinFormSamples and the `Different kind of layers supported by [MapBox]` Example. The map is showing the overlay only while magnifying and not fully function but maybe a good hint